# Bypass primary DNS for one domain

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns

I need to use my default DNS as primary, but for second I could use Google's one which is already updated.

I would like to use Google's DNS for a specific domain which has changed IP and is still not refreshing on the primary DNS.

Is it possible?

Comment: Not only would this not work, it could also hide problems you may be having with your specific domain.

Comment: Can you use a hosts file entry?

Comment: @ewwhite: yes, I have complete access to it

Comment: Have you cleared the DNS server cache on the primary DNS server?

Comment: @joeqwerty: I fear I don't have access to that machine.. unless servers are smart enough to accept by users (not by their admin) a "refresh this dns command"

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible for you to do it, if your infrastructure can use DNS Response Policy Zones.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Response_policy_zone

Note that this will only work for machines you control. If you care about the wider world getting to the correct record, they won't be using your RPZ settings.

In all cases, you should work with your DNS providers to get accurate data, and ensure that you're not setting high TTLs thus shooting yourself in the foot when you make changes.

/And as Ed says, HOSTS entries can be a good bandaid/crutch, but they're even better at putting lead in your toes later.

Comment: Could you specify that this will work *if* he doesn't add Google's DNS as a secondary? Since otherwise there's no guarantee which server will be used to resolve and it may not use the RPZ one.

Comment: As I said, this only works for infrastructure that @Revious controls. I doubt that includes Google's DNS servers.

Comment: Given the level of the question I figured it'd be best to be explicit, but alright then.

Comment: I've also tried to add to the hosts file this line of code: ns33.keliweb.com www.mysite.com but it seems not to work... Is hosts file accepting only ip?

Comment: You'll definitely want to get yourself up to speed on DNS and related topics. The HOSTS file is for name-to-IP mappings. It is not a local DNS and doesn't support (for example) CNAME, SRV, TXT records.